# Editing finalized Workflow items creates new finalized version in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

So I'm new to Sitecore (6.5) and I'm having a situation in a workflow where copying or editing a workflow item in a finalized state creates a new item already finalized; bypassing the lock and edit I've verified that the users are not admins. Any assistance would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

On your workflow item can you confirm you have the initial state set to your first state in your workflow. E.g Draft.

[image]

Then on your item you want the workflow on, Do you have your workflow configured (Setting only the default workflow field) on the standard values as below?

[image]

Comment: thanks for the info. i'll give it a shot and see what shakes out.

Comment: No problem. Also make sure you have lock and edited switched on. When you lock and edit an item that's approved then it should create a new version and put the item back in the first state of workflow. (as long as they aren't administrators)